# change background color of a section and border-bottom color of a header with javascript

Tags: javascript, background, border

I am trying to change the background color of a section and a border-bottom color of a header when a button in corresponding color is clicked. For example when the blue button is clicked I want the background color of the section to change into this color : rgb(203, 223, 242) and the bottom border of the header to change into rgb(225, 255, 255).

I have tried with document.getElementsByTagName('section') and I retrieve the section tag, but after that when I attempt to change the background color with the following piece of code secColor.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(203, 223, 242)' nothing happens.

Thank you in advance!

Here is part of the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>List</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="StyleSheet.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section>
            <header>
                <form>
                    <button>&#8362;</button>
                    <div>
                        <p>Colors</p>
                        <button id="blue" onclick="functionBlueSection('rgb(203, 223, 242)'); functionBlueHeader('(225, 255, 255)');"></button>
                        <button id="red" onclick="functionRedSection(); functionRedHeader();"></button>
                        <button id="yellow" onclick="functionYellowSection(), functionYellowHeader()"></button>
                     </div>
                  </form>

            </header>
                 <ul>
                    <li> 
                        <a href="#">List item</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Sublist item</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Sublist item</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Sublist item</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Sublist item</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                    </li>                                   
                </ul>
        </section>

        <!--Javascript-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
           function functionBlueSection()  {
  var secColor = document.getElementsByTagName('section');
  secColor.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(203, 223, 242)';
   }

            var headColor = document.getElementsByTagName('header');
            function functionBlueHeader(){
                headColor.style.borderBottom = 'thin solid rgb(225, 255, 255)';
            }

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add jquery to your project 
add a`<script src=""` tag, (see the jquery website on how to add) and avoid -  inline onClick attributes are not in use anymore.

the following code should help you after inserting jQuery, and chaging the properties to the desired result:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#red').on("click",function(){
 this.css("border","1px solid blue");
 this.css("background","yellow");

});


$('#blue').on("click",function(){
 this.css("border","1px solid blue");
 this.css("background","yellow");
});

$('#yellow').on("click",function(){
 this.css("border","1px solid blue");
 this.css("background","yellow");
 });

});
```